# Written Equation To Python Code

Tags: python

How can I get this equation in python code.  Its supposed to equal .343 but when I type it out I always get something else.  When I calculate it on paper I'm able to get it but in excel/python I'm unable to.

[image: Equation]

What I have tried:

```
((.310*.290)/.260)/(.310*.290)/(.260+((1-.310)*(1-.290)/1-.260))
```

which gives me `7.85`

Comment: I don't think there's a way to salvage this question that won't end up with it being closed. However, here is the equation with parentheses that work: `0.31*0.29/0.26/(0.31*0.29/0.26+(1-0.31)*(1-0.29)/(1-0.26))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the both the expression under the division bar in parentheses:

```
>>> (
...     (.310 * .290) / .260
...     /
...     (
...         (.310 * .290) / .260
...         +
...         ((1 - .310) * (1 - .290) / (1 - .260))
...     )
... )
0.3430943785456421
```

This ensures that the addition of the two parts under the bar takes place *before* dividing the upper expression result.

You didn't do that in your attempt, so you essentially get this instead:

```
(
    ((.310 * .290) / .260)
    /
    (.310 * .290)
    /
    (
        .260
        + 
        (
            (1 - .310) * (1 - .290) / 1
            -
            .260
        )
    )
)
```

I split both my and your attempts out according to precedence rules. Notice the difference?

The result of `(.310 * .290)` should first be divided `.260` and have the rest of the expression under the bar summed to it; your version divides the outcome from above the bar by that much first, then *that* result is divided by the outcome of `.260 + ...`. That's not the same expression.

Some of the parentheses even in the original expression are redundant. Multiplication and division goes before addition and subtraction, so we can remove parentheses around multiplication and division:

```
(
     .310 * .290 / .260
     /
     (.310 * .290 / .260 + (1 - .310) * (1 - .290) / (1 - .260))
)
```

or all on one line:

```
>>> .310 * .290 / .260 / (.310 * .290 / .260 + (1 - .310) * (1 - .290) / (1 - .260))
0.3430943785456421
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(((.310 * .290) / .260) / (((.310 * .290) / .260) + ( (1-.310) * (1 - .290) / (1 - .260))))
```